# Returning/Getting DataGrid Row index from button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having trouble returning which row a button was clicked from in my wpf project.

I have the following so far...

XAML -

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="550">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="200">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="RowEvent">X</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

C# -

```
    private void RowEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
    }
```

I seem to recall that when I was using a dataGridView in Win Forms I could get the row index from e.RowIndex if I remember correctly, but I cant seem to do that this time.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

[DataGrid.SelectedIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) Property

... like this:

```
    private void RowEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = myDataGrid.SelectedIndex;
        MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            myDataGrid.GetColumn(btn);
            myDataGrid.GetRow(btn);
            MessageBox.Show(myDataGrid.GetColumn(btn).ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(myDataGrid.GetRow(btn).ToString());
        }
```

This is how i managed it! I just used the click event of the button

Comment: What didn't work? Are you receiving the right event?

Comment: Grid is his grid. The grid which is being referenced. Just edited the answer to make it fit.

Comment: does WPF datagrid have a GetColumn?